# Adding Login page to Rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on ROR apps and Mongo DB , App has two controller : 
1) Portfolio  --- All method related to admin.

2) Target ----  All actions which are used for public display of data.

Now I want to put a log in page into my website so only login users can see views related to portfolio ? How can I do that. Any lead will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into either RailsAdmin:

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

Or try ActiveAdmin:

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin

They both include Devise, as suggested by grotori, and give you admin panel functionality out of the box.

If you're using Mongoid, you'd also want to look at:

https://github.com/elia/activeadmin-mongoid

RailsAdmin also supports Mongoid by default.

Comment: I already have an existing app and I am using mongo db? app- www.niveshi.com

Comment: RailsAdmin also supports Mongoid. ActiveAdmin doesn't, but there is also: https://github.com/elia/activeadmin-mongoid

Comment: I have a doubt i don't want any admin panel, i already have every action which i need.I just need to put that under sign -in.I edited my admin thing to sign in user.

Comment: If you've got a use case for one, then you'll probably have more. Secondly, administrators often like to see a different interface for their high-level view of the app, versus ordinary users which have a less powerful set of features.

Comment: Ultimately I don't know what exactly your use case is, but the Ruby on Rails community has a set of tools for these sorts of problems, and it wouldn't hurt to leverage them if you can.

Comment: what are the changes does i have to do in active_admin so that only admin is able to access actions in portfolio controller?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an administrator panel, you can just use Devise:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

You can then use `user_signed_in?` to control what is shown to the user. In other words:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  Only signed in users can see this message!
<% end %>
```